# How to use SimpleDateFormat in Widget RemoteViewsFactory class?

Tags: android, widget, simpledateformat, date-format, remoteview

I need to format date and time in the RemoteViewsFactory class. I know how to use DateFormat/SimpleDate Format. I'm doing it like in the thread below but the app keeps stopping when pressing on the widget on a physical device:    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvTaskDay, DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(task.getDay()));

[Android - ListView items inside app widget not selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521952/android-listview-items-inside-app-widget-not-selectable)

I'm also formatting in the parent activity and it works. Is it possible to reference the SimpleDateFormat code from there? Thank you in advance.

P.S. Error message. 
My RemoteViewsFactory class:

```
public class ScheduleWidgetViewFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory
{
    private ArrayList<Schedule> mScheduleList;
    private Context mContext;

    public ScheduleWidgetViewFactory(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged()
    {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Schedule>>() {}.getType();
        String gsonString = sharedPreferences.getString("ScheduleList_Widget", "");
        mScheduleList = gson.fromJson(gsonString, type);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mScheduleList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
    {
        Schedule schedule = mScheduleList.get(position);

        RemoteViews itemView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.schedule_widget_list_item);

        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_station_name, schedule.getStationScheduleName());
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_arrival, DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(schedule.getExpectedArrival()));
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_towards, schedule.getDirectionTowards());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(ScheduleWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, schedule);
        itemView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.schedule_widget_list, intent);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Parent Activity:

```
 @Override
    public void returnScheduleData(ArrayList<Schedule> simpleJsonScheduleData)
    {
        if (simpleJsonScheduleData.size() > 0)
        {
            scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(simpleJsonScheduleData, StationScheduleActivity.this);
            scheduleArrayList = simpleJsonScheduleData;
            mScheduleRecyclerView.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);
            scheduleAdapter.setScheduleList(scheduleArrayList);

            stationArrival = scheduleArrayList.get(0);

            stationShareStationName = stationArrival.getStationScheduleName();
            stationShareArrivalTime = stationArrival.getExpectedArrival();
            stationShareDirection = stationArrival.getDirectionTowards();

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            Date date = null;

            try {
                date = simpleDateFormat.parse(stationArrival.getExpectedArrival());
                date.toString();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String finalDate = newDateFormat.format(date);

            stationShareArrivalTime = finalDate;

            //Store Schedule Info in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(scheduleArrayList);
            prefsEditor.putString("ScheduleList_Widget", json);
            prefsEditor.apply();
        }
        else
        {
            emptySchedule.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the [complete stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: @MikeM.Question updated.

Comment: If your app is crashing, then there will be a stack trace from the crash in the logcat. Have a look at [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174) and [this developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat) for help in finding that.

Comment: @MikeM.Error message copied and pasted.

Comment: Those logs are likely unrelated to your crash. You're looking for [the stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174), which should be a large section of red lines, starting with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. You can use the filters above the log window to make it easier to find. Also, when you find it, please post the whole thing.

Comment: @MikeM.No stack trace. It happens when I select the widget from the widget menu. Only these messages in red: 2019-01-19 23:08:34.637 27793-27793/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-01-19 23:08:34.639 27793-27793/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2019-01-19 23:08:34.639 27793-27793/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory

Comment: Well, if you can't find it, then I would suggest that you start setting breakpoints in your code, and step through with the debugger to determine exactly where the crash is happening, and what the current local values are. If you still need assistance after that, you'll need to put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @MikeM.I can't seem to debug for some reason, but I've figured out that the widget crashes due to the date format code. It works again when I change it back to:    itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_arrival, schedule.getExpectedArrival());

Comment: If that works without crashing, then it would seem that `schedule.getExpectedArrival()` is returning a `String`, or some other `CharSequence`. If so, then you're passing the wrong thing to `DateFormat#format()`, which expects a `Number` or a `Date`. If you're trying to reformat a date/time string, you need to `parse()` it first to get a `Date`, then `format()` that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12503542

Comment: @MikeM.Thank you for the link. I know how to format date and time. As you see in the code sample above, I've used it in the parent activity. Here, I'm not sure how to implement the Date/SimpleDateFormat code in the RemoteViewsFactory class.

Comment: The fact that it's in a `RemoteViewsFactory` is irrelevant. It works the same everywhere. You need to parse it first, then format.

Comment: @MikeM.Solved! I'm just starting out with widgets. Can you please put your comments in an answer so that I can give you points? Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) It was only a few quick pointers. Nothing major. You actually had the right code already. You just forgot a step when you put it in the `RemoteViewsFactory`. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like, or to delete this, if you'd rather. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has is stuck on this. As Mike M. pointed out in the comments, the DateFormat code structure in RemoteViewsFactory is the same as everywhere else.

```
 private String stationWidgetArrivalTime;

 @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)
    {
        Schedule schedule = mScheduleList.get(position);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(schedule.getExpectedArrival());
            date.toString();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String finalDate = newDateFormat.format(date);

        stationWidgetArrivalTime = finalDate;

        RemoteViews itemView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.schedule_widget_list_item);

        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_station_name, schedule.getStationScheduleName());
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_arrival, stationWidgetArrivalTime);
        itemView.setTextViewText(R.id.schedule_widget_towards, schedule.getDirectionTowards());

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(ScheduleWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, schedule);
        itemView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.schedule_widget_list, intent);

        return itemView;
    }
```